# ios - add loading indicator at the bottom of uicollectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

in iOS is there any built in support for adding a "loader" (UIActivityIndicator) to a uicollectionview, such that every time a user scroll to the last cell of data he'll see another horizontal subview with the loading indicator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no "built in" way. What you'd need to do is have an extra cell that contains a loader. It's fairly trivial to detect when this cell appears, at which point you can start the call to load more data.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [data count] + 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UICollectionViewCell *cell;

   if (indexPath.item < [data count])
   {
      cell = ...; // regular cell
   }
   else
   {
      cell = ...; // cell with loading indicator
   }

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but my loader cell won't be constantly displaying, but only partially. This will cause changes to the collectionView content size which in turn will give me too much white space in the bottom of my the scrollview. How can I overcome this?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean it will only be partially displaying? Can you provide a mockup of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I think @vondip means that the footer is only visible if the number of loaded items is less than the total number of items available.

Comment: theres an another way i've wrote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36639431/3308174)