# How to add loading Indicator in Footer of CollectionView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

How can I add loading Indicator in the Footer of collection view when data is loaded for next page..?

[image]

I want to loading indicator in Footer of Collection view as same as above image.
But I can not able to do this.

So Is it possible or not..? Otherwise, I have to create this type of list view using tableview. Because We can easily manage this things into tableview.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios - add loading indicator at the bottom of uicollectionview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742800/ios-add-loading-indicator-at-the-bottom-of-uicollectionview)

Comment: @Vizllx : Yess I have already check this answer too. I want easy and best way to do this. Otherwise I will go to with Tableview.

Comment: You have no where mentioned in your question that you have already gone through this question and as off now the best solution of doing it with collection view is this in my way. So next time you post any question in SO mention what you have done so far and what references you have followed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one very easy solution with help of [CCBottomRefreshControl](https://github.com/vlasov/CCBottomRefreshControl)
You need to just treat it like simple UIRefreshController

```
let bottomRefreshController = UIRefreshControl()
bottomRefreshController.triggerVerticalOffset = 50
bottomRefreshController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshBottom), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

collectionView.bottomRefreshControl = bottomRefreshController

func refreshBottom() {
     //api call for loading more data
     loadMoreData() 
}
```

and where you think you should stop loader simply

```
collectionView.bottomRefreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

Answer (score 8):

The simplest solution would be adding the activity indicator to a view and add that view to UICollectionReusableView.

In collection view :

```
private let footerView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.white)


  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.register(CollectionViewFooterView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer")
        (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.footerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 50)
        
    }

   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter {
            let footer = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", for: indexPath)
            footer.addSubview(footerView)
            footerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 50)
            return footer
        }
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
```

customized class: add your customizations here if you need any

```
public class CollectionViewFooterView: UICollectionReusableView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

just use: footerView.startAnimating() & footerView.stopAnimating() for start or stop the animation

*****  Hope you like it .******

Comment: Thanks for this solution, what if we need for tableview? both grouped tableview and normal?

Comment: Bottom of collectionview always have 50 extra height as footer, what about that?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way it that add an UIView at the bottom of your ViewController add an ActivityIndicator to that view and set view's property hidden to checked, create an IBOutlet of that view, while loading data from server set outlet's property hidden=NO after data is loaded again hide the view.
The same thing I've done in few of my apps using UICollectionViews or UITableView

**EDIT**

An another way is to add loading indicator in the footer of either CollectionView or tableview then make a network call in the below method

For CollectionView:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplaySupplementaryView:(UICollectionReusableView *)view forElementKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

And For TableView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayFooterView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

**Swift 4.2**

For CollectionView:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplaySupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath)
```

For TableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
```

Comment: Why would you be making the network call in those methods?

Comment: @userx it will feel like it's infinit. It's important to keep our track for network call that it doesn't get called repeatedly

Answer (score 1):

Form Interface builder,

In `Attribute inspector` with your `Collection View` selected check the `Section Footer` in `Accessories`. So, It will add footerview in your collection view and you can easily drag and drop activity indicator to this `footerView`.

Hope this can help you. :)

Comment: Yes, I tried this. But not succeeded into this. Please give me example with code. So I can easily understand this.

Answer (score 1):

the open source libiary [MJRefresh](https://github.com/CoderMJLee/MJRefresh) is a good choice,  you can easily add a refresh foot . if you want use the same animation of your image, maybe you should use MJRefreshAutoGifFooter class with a gif image.  the project include the same example , you can download and try it on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Footer in collection view is a bit tricky in my thoughts , so man ! just take an extra section of only 1 item with a custom cell in which you will add the loading indicator like below...

```
class IndicatorCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var indicator : UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let view = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        view.style = .large
        return view
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupIndicator()
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        print(self.frame.size)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupIndicator()
    }
    
    func setupIndicator(){
        indicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(indicator)
        indicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        indicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        indicator.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

And then check on your collectionView methods for the last section with indicator cell item and show with required sizeForItem.

Boom ! Thats the easiest solution/hack I've taken...

**Note: Don't forget to register the cell class**